# Display message in tableview cell if array is empty

Tags: swift, label, tableview

How can I display a label in a specific cell notifying the users if there is no data available? For example, I have a collection view inside of a tableview cell. I'm getting information from my server to see if the user has listed their favorite movies. If they haven't, I would like to display a message saying no movies have been chosen. Thanks in advance.

```
// arrays to hold server information
var movies = [AnyObject]()

// tableview cell configuration
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            // declare the header cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieDisplayHeader") as! MovieChosenByYouTVC

            return cell

        } else {


            // declare the second cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MovieDisplay") as! MovieDisplayTVC

            tableView.reloadData()


            // reload the collection view data
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()

            return cell

            }

        }

    } // end of configuring the cell
```